# jqxgrid loading twice when using d3.js chart

Tags: django, d3.js, crossfilter, jqxgrid

I am using latest **d3.js** library along with **jqxgrid** for analysis in a **django** application for one of my client. The graphical representation of data is done through d3.js while actual data is displayed using jqxgrid. My issue is that when I **filter the jqxgrid** using d3 '**brushend**' function, the **grid is loaded twice**. The **loadComplete** function of jqxgrid is used to load data to jqxgrid. Could you please tell me what may be the issue and its workaround?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi All, I am using Crossfilter javascript library along with d3.js and jqxgrid. Thanks in advance.